# button change text c#

Tags: c#, button, text, label

im trying to make a button change a label. I was able to do it before but i cant anymore.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Click)
            label1.Text == ("Lawl");
    }
}
```

It comes up with 2 errors:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`button1.Click` is an event, not a property. Assuming you've set `button1_Click()` as an event handler for `Click` using the Designer, you can simply remove that `if` altogether and write:

```
label1.Text = "Lawl";
```

Note also the single `=` since you want assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
=
```

Is the assign operator.

```
==
```

Is the equality operator.

```
label1.Text == ("Lawl");
```

Is interpreted as label1's text equal to "Lawl"

You should write instead:

```
label1.Text = "Lawl";
```

Which is read as: assign "lawl" to label1's text property.

Edit (didn't even see the if...):

Also button1.click is an event, not a property.

Comment: Not the only problem: `button1.Click` is an event and doesn't belong in an `if`.

Comment: I've edited the first answer, didn't notice it, sorry.